# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 dylib linkage

Tags: c++, xcode, dylib, linkage

I trying to compile my c++ project which includes a dylib(this dylib is another personal project).

I configured all my xcode project by adding the dylib in the build phase(and adding headers) but i still have "**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64**" on all functions included in the dylib.

I don't see what i missed
Any Idea?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

I did a mistake in dylib generation. I forgot to define marco export 
`__attribute__((visibility("default")))`

All works well now.